# Show product by ID at single product page

Tags: php, laravel, e-commerce, product

I have a problem showing just one product at the single product page. So if I click a product now at the front page I want to see that specific product.

Now I am seeing all products instead of the product I clicked.

This is the route:

```
Route::get('/product/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'productController@getProduct',
    'as' => 'product.single'
]);
```

This is the Controller:

```
public function getProduct($id)    
{
    $product = Product::find($id);
    return view('pages.product', ['id' => $product->id]);
}
```

This is the view (product.blade.php):

```
@foreach(App\Product::all() as $product)
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src= {{$product->imagePath}} alt="...">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3> {{$product->title}} </h3>
                <p class="discription"> {{$product->discription}} </p>
                <div class="clearfix">
                    <div class="pull-left price"/>$ {{$product->price}}</div>
                <a href= {{ route('product.addToCart', ['id' => $product->id ]) }} class="btn btn-danger pull-right" role="button">Add to cart</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: This is wrong on many levels.  how could you write `@foreach(App\Product::all() as $product)` and expect it to show a single product? Voting to close as too broad

Comment: Man i'm just learning, you don't have to answer if you are not helping me

Comment: I am not trying to be rude. I just do not think you are learning anything by asking questions like this. You should be working on the fundamentals (variables, control structures), not a complex mvc framework.

Answer (score 0):

In your view you are looping through all the products with

```
@foreach(App\Product::all() as $product)
```

That's what's causing the error.

You need to first return the product from your controller properly

```
$product = Product::find($id);
return view('pages.product', ['product' => $product]);
```

Then in your view you only display one product

```
<img src= {{$product->imagePath}} alt="...">
<div class="caption">
    <h3> {{$product->title}} </h3>
    <p class="discription"> {{$product->discription}} </p>
    <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="pull-left price"/>$ {{$product->price}}</div>
        <a href= {{ route('product.addToCart', ['id' => $product->id ]) }} class="btn btn-danger pull-right" role="button">Add to cart</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a `Product` object. So, change controller method to:

```
public function getProduct($id)
{
    $product = Product::find($id);
    return view('pages.product', ['product' => $product]);
}
```

And in the view you need to remove `@foreach and @endforeach`

Comment: Thank you for your comment!

Comment: Hi, why is laravel changing my route to:  .../public/product/js/bootstrap.min.js

Answer (score 0):

Change your `getProduct` function to return:

```
return view('pages.product', ['product' => $product]);
```